# Removing certains lines from files using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-re

I am trying to remove single, multiline comments, headers files and certain lines from a java code using re function. This code worked previously. But now it is showing unexpected errors.

Basically this script should remove everyline starting with ("//" , /* and end with */, "package", "import")

```
     import re
     with open('H:\\APK_Source_Code_Merged\\abc.txt', 'r',encoding= 'utf-8', errors= 'ignore') as fil:
     file = fil.read()
     wtalc = re.sub(r"//.?", '', file, flags=re.S)
     wtslc = re.sub(r"/*.?*/", '', wtalc, flags=re.S)
     wtslc = re.sub(r"package.?\*/", '', wtalc, flags=re.S)
     wtblc = re.sub(r"import.?", '', wtslc, flags=re.S)
     print(wtblc)
```

[image]

Comment: Please can you copy/paste the code rather than doing a screenshot

Comment: Hi, I already pasted the code along with a screenshot. Sorry